# Distribution over the time it takes for a random process to reach an upper threshold

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am trying to figure out a way of determining the distribution over the time it takes for an arbitrary random process to cross a threshold value.

For example, a simple (solved) case would be the Poisson process. In the Poisson process, the intervals between increments are exponentially distributed. Therefore the time it takes a Poisson process (starting at $0$) to reach $n$ is the sum of $n$ independent exponentially distributed random variables. The distribution over this sum is given by the exponential distribution convolved with itself $n$ times.

I am trying to generalize this result for an arbitrary random process. Here's what I have so far:

Let $\Delta t$ be the amount of time it takes for a random process $\{ x(t) \}$ to cross an upper threshold $r$.

$$
p(\Delta t = \Delta T) = \frac{d}{d\Delta T}p(\Delta t < \Delta T),
$$

where $p(\Delta t < \Delta T)$ is the cumulative distribution of $\Delta t$.

$$
p(\Delta t < \Delta T) = 1 - p(\Delta t \geq \Delta T),
$$

and $\Delta t \geq \Delta T$ is the equivalent event of $x(t) < r, \forall t < \Delta T$. Thus, one could find the probability that the random process stays below $r$ for all times less than $\Delta T$. This also seems like a difficult calculation, though, as it seems like it would involve a complex joint probability.

Are there any tricks to solving this kind of problem? Or are there any other cases where it has been solved (such as in Brownian motion?

Comment: It's been solved for Brownian Motion: http://www.opentradingsystem.com/quantNotes/Brownian_motion_hitting_a_barrier_.html